# How to set automatic page breaks on TCPDF when a row in a table does not fit in the page?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I made a table in TCPDF using html. Now, I need to determine if a table row will fit in the page since their height varies depending on the data they hold.

If the row's content won't fit because it has a big height or the row's content already reached past the footer, it will be instead printed to the next page. How can I achieve this? I'm still new to TCPDF.

Thanks for your help!

Example: (in this case, Employee 3 row doesn't fit because Employee 2 row's height is high and will be printed at the 2nd page)

Page 1

### Employee Name || Earning || Deduction || Net Pay

---

Employee 1

```
                      - ALLOWANCE   - TAX           20,000.00
                      - N.SHIFT     - H. PLAN
                      - LUNCH ALW   - LOAN
                                    - LOAN 2
                                    - LOAN 3
```

Employee 2

```
                      - ALLOWANCE   - TAX           18,000.00
                      - N.SHIFT     - H. PLAN
                      - LUNCH ALW   - LOAN
                                    - LOAN 2
                                    - LOAN 3 
                                    - LOAN 4
                                    - LOAN 5 
                                    - LOAN 6
                                    - LOAN 7
```

---

Page 2

### Employee Name || Earning || Deduction || Net Pay

---

Employee 3

```
                      - ALLOWANCE   - TAX           30,000.00
                      - LUNCH ALW   - H. PLAN
                                    - LOAN
                                    - LOAN 2
                                    - LOAN 3 
                                    - LOAN 4
```

---

Comment: and `SetAutoPageBreak` method not work correctly?

Comment: Not really, I have a row that was cut because it's already at the footer, I need it to be at the next page.

Comment: http://imgur.com/TMix2Wr here is my sample report. I just followed the basic instruction of the TCPDF tutorial with tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might help you: [TCPDF multipage table page break in multiline cell problem](http://www.herikstad.net/2011/01/tcpdf-multipage-table-page-break-in.html).

You just have to use following tag on each `<tr>` element.

```
<tr nobr="true">
  <td>your content here</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: (-_-)...seriously ...can't believe that worked. @walkingRed thanks!! ...not sure who down voted you though :/